# Problem getting CouchDB running w. Django

Tags: django, couchdb, couchdbkit

I'm having trouble getting my Django project to work with a CouchDB database.

I'm running Python 2.6.6, Django 1.3, and Lion on a Mac

I've got Django, CouchDB, and CouchDBKit installed.  I can import all of them from the python interpreter without a problem.  If I go to my CouchDB database URL, I can see the db.

The problem is, when I try to go to my django project URL, I get the following error:

```
You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.
```

I have the following lines in my settings.py file:

```
COUCHDB_DATABASES = (
('my_project.my_db', 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_db'),
)
```

The only possible solution I've found so far, is to set a throwaway database in the normal database engine settings.  But, this just throws another error, because Django starts looking for database tables in the throw away DB.

**Edit with new info:**
I'm accessing my DB via an SSH tunnel
I'm able to create and access a CouchDB from the python interpeter.
I've run a test from the python interpreter, to access the app DB (again, via the tunnel), and the returned data accurately.
It's just when I try to access the actual site from a browser URL, I get the engine not defined error.

Django seems to be trying to use a normal DB (which isn't setup), instead of the CouchDB.

Any ideas?

Comment: Searching with the goog gets a bunch of hits, I think you'll find your answer(s) within those (the first couple are quite good)

Comment: Found my problem - was actually an issue with one of the views Django was using, trying to use a property that didn't exist.

Comment: post as an answer and accept it, others may find it useful in the future.